# Interdependent class templates design?

Tags: c++, class, templates, c++11

Consider the following design :

```
template <class SecondType>
struct First
{
    SecondType* _ptr;
};

template <class FirstType>
struct Second
{
    FirstType* _ptr;
};
```

where the `First` type has a pointer to a `Second` type and vice-versa. The problem is that I cannot declare this because they are interdependent and I should declare `First<Second<First<Second...>>>`.

How to solve this problem ?

Comment: What exactly is this emulating?

Comment: Why the above class design? What real-life problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe a work-around with something that looks like [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) but even crazier:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class SecondType>
struct FirstBase
{
    SecondType* _ptr;
};

template <class FirstType>
struct SecondBase
{
    FirstType* _ptr;
};

struct FirstDerived
: public FirstBase<SecondBase<FirstDerived>>
{
};

struct SecondDerived
: public SecondBase<FirstBase<SecondDerived>>
{
};

int main()
{
    FirstBase<SecondDerived> x;
    SecondBase<FirstDerived> y;
    return 0;
}
```

If someone has a more elegant way to do this, I would be happy to see it.

Comment: I would assume you didn't want us to change the templates too much  because to do it without the templates would be easy

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve but the following compiles fine.

```
template <class T> struct First  { T* _ptr; };
template <class T> struct Second { T* _ptr; };

int main(){
   First<Second<First<Second<void>>>> a; // or
   First<Second<First<Second<nullptr_t>>>> b;
   return 0;
}
```

Note I replaced FirstType, SecondType altogether cos it does not matter. T would be replaced by whatever you pass and this will happen when the template is being specialized before compilation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another possibly more elegant solution which doesn't require void at all. I don't know if the inheritance is acceptable to you but I think it works well.

```
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
struct Base {
    //make all functions virtual
};
template <class SecondType>
struct First: public Base
{
    SecondType* _ptr;
    First(SecondType * st) {
        _ptr = st;
    }
    First() {
    }
};

template <class FirstType>
struct Second: public Base
{
    FirstType* _ptr;
    Second(FirstType * ft) {
        _ptr = ft;
    }
    Second() {
    }
};

int main() {
    First<Base> f;
    Second<Base>  s;
    f._ptr = &s;
    s._ptr = &f;
    cout << s._ptr << endl;
}
```